# How can I display a Base64 encoded image in Android using Coil?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, base64, png, coil

I'm attempting to display a PNG image encoded as a Base64 string in an Android app using Coil, but nothing shows up. My Base64 string starts like this:
`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo...`
and I'm trying to decode and display using Coil.

Here's the code snippet:

```
val base64ImageString = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo..." // Your Base64 string here    
val imageLoader = ImageLoader(context)
val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
    .data(base64ImageString)
    .target(imageView)
    .build()

imageLoader.enqueue(request)
```

Comment: When it starts with `data:image/png;base64,`, it's not a Base64 string. The Base64 encoding does not define any prefixes. It is not a Base64 string, but a [Data-URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) that contains a Base64 string. This is unfortunately a common misunderstanding that leads to exactly the problems you had.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the issue was due to not properly stripping the data:image/png;base64, prefix before decoding the Base64 string. Here’s the corrected approach:

```
// Kotlin code snippet
val base64ImageStringWithPrefix = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo..." // Full Base64 string
val base64ImageString = base64ImageStringWithPrefix.substringAfter("base64,")

val imageByteArray = Base64.decode(base64ImageString, Base64.DEFAULT)

// Use Coil to load the byte array into the ImageView
val imageLoader = ImageLoader(context)
val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
    .data(imageByteArray)
    .target(imageView)
    .listener(
        onError = { _, throwable ->
            // Log or handle the error
            throwable.printStackTrace()
        }
    )
    .build()

imageLoader.enqueue(request)
```